# Continue with out a default route?

Tags: 12.04, preseed

I am doing a complete unattended install of Ubuntu 12.04. I am doing static network configuration. Here is content for Static network configuration from the preseed file.

```
d-i netcfg/disable_dhcp boolean true
d-i netcfg/no_default_route boolean true
d-i netcfg/get_nameservers string 192.168.1.254
d-i netcfg/get_ipaddress string 192.168.1.13
d-i netcfg/get_netmask string 255.255.255.0
d-i netcfg/get_gateway string 192.168.1.1
d-i netcfg/confirm_static boolean true
```

Still is asking "Continue without a default route?". I have to say , then only installed is going ahead. Am passing preseed file via network (preseed/url). How to avoid this manual intervention? Does the order of `netcfg` statements matter?

Comment: A "default route" is used as a last-case fallback for routing IP packets, if none of the other entries in the routing table match. Why would not want a "default route"? I'd suggest 192.168.1.1 in your example.